# Indexing for a Greater/Less than query

Tags: mysql, indexing

I am trying to do an update between two very large tables (millions of records)

```
Update TableA as T1
Inner Join TableB as T2
On T1.Field1=T2.Field1
And T1.Value >= T2.MinValue
And T1.Value <= T2.MaxValue
Set T1.Field2=T2.Field2
```

I have indexes on all the fields individually in both tables, Value fields included. They are all Normal/BTree (default).

Is there some better way to index the value fields to get better performance? It is adding a huge overhead to what is otherwise (using just =) a pretty fast update otherwise. My first test too 3 minutes to update 25 records and I have 5 million to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, only one index per table can be used for a particular `WHERE` clause. So if it uses the index on `Field1`, it won't be able to use the index on `Value`, and vice versa. The solution is to use a composite index:

```
ALTER TABLE TableA ADD INDEX (Field1, Value);
```

Since an index on multiple columns is effectively an index on any prefix set of the columns, you can remove the individual index on `Field1` when you add this index. But you should still keep the individual index on `Value` if that's needed for other queries.